# URL to the latest revision of Conan package in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

We are using Artifactory to distribute Conan packages.
Our Conan packages also contain an archive with the Doxygen documentation that I need to link to. (Subsequently referred to as "file.zip")

For various reasons, we have to use `revisions_enabled=1` in our conan.conf and we upload several revisions to the Artifactory during our release process.

I already know that I can have a URL for the file using this format:
[https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/projectX/user/module/2.3.4/release/[HASH]/export/conan_sources.tgz!/module/file.zip](https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/projectX/user/module/2.3.4/release/%5BHASH%5D/export/conan_sources.tgz!/module/file.zip)

However, since we have multiple revisions, I always have to find out the hash of the most recent revision (which I know could be automated) and update all the URLs accordingly wherever they are being used in our intranet.

**I'm looking for a way to generate a URL that always links to the file in the *latest* revision.**

I know that Conan automatically gets the latest revision. However, those links are a convenient and easy way to immediately have the documentation in our download folder, which is also nice even for non-developers.